# su cannot find script in path

Tags: linux, su, amazon-ec2

On AWS EC2 instance I have the following script that runs at startup under the root user

```
cd /home/ec2-user/lutze     
su -p -c "python -m lutze" ec2-user
```

The script runs without a problem but it call another script which cannot be found and it raises an error "umi_tools not found".

now this other script resides in **/home/ec2-user/umi-tools** and it appears in the **PATH** under **/home/ec2-user/.local/bin/umi_tools** .
If I login directly into the machine as ec2-user I've no problem running umi-tools from whatever directory I'm in.

What can be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: you can try `su - -p -c` to get the target user environment

Comment: Using `su -p -c 'echo $PATH'` (single quotes `'`, not double `"`) will show you the `$PATH` in the context that you're trying to run `python -m lutze`. I suspect that the necessary directory is not in the `PATH`

Comment: Be safe and set the `PATH` you need in your scripts!